# Series inequalities and their limit

Tags: calculus

Is it true to say that if $a_n \geq b_n$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n) \geq \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(b_n)$ and if not can I have a counter-example?

Thanks!

Comment: Or this (older) one [How do you prove this limit inequality?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720204/how-do-you-prove-this-limit-inequality)

Comment: Great! the second one really helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is true:
$$
a_n \geq b_n \implies \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n \geq \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n
$$ by the [limit definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition).