# How to show that $\lim a_n\geq\lim b_n$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $(a_n),(b_n)$ are two convergent sequences such that there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\geq b_n$ for all $n\geq N$. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$

This is an obvious fact but I'm not sure how to formalize the proof.

Take the subsequences $a_{n_k}$ and $b_{n_k}$ which are defined to be the $N$th tail of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ respectively. Since every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit, we have $$\lim a_n=\lim a_{n_k}\geq \lim b_{n_k}=\lim b_n.$$

Is there a better proof than this?

Comment: "Better" can be in the eyes of the beholder: what you wrote is most probably the easiest, shortest proof. For me, this means "better".

Comment: The $N$th tail of a sequence $(a_n)$ is the subsequence containing every point including and after $a_N$.

Comment: Then, I agree with DonAntonio

Comment: I was probably looking for a lower level argument using $\epsilon-\delta$

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720204/how-do-you-prove-this-limit-inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ and suppose $a<b$. Fix $\varepsilon:=\frac{b-a}{3}$. Then 
$$
a_n<a+\varepsilon<b-\varepsilon<b_n
$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large. This contradicts the hypothesis $a_n \ge b_n$ eventually.

Ps. I wouldn't call it "better".